Finding the least squares solution of a linear system based on a QR factorization
One method of finding the least squares solution of the following "augmented system"
$$
\left[
\begin{matrix}
I & A \\
A^T & O
\end{matrix}
\right]
\left[
\begin{matrix}
r \\
x
\end{matrix}
\right]
=
\left[
\begin{matrix}
b \\
c
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$
by iterative refinement (see for example 3(c) of this document) is based on the QR factorization
$$
A = Q \left[
\begin{matrix}
R \\
0
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$
so that
$$
R x = (d_1 - z)
$$
$$
y = Q \left[
\begin{matrix}
d_1 \\
d_2
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$
where
$$
Rz = c
$$
$$
\left[
\begin{matrix}
d_1 \\
d_2
\end{matrix}
\right] = Q^T b
$$

All this seems clear.  The problem is that I can't seem to apply the this procedure. For example if
$$c = 0$$
$$
A^T = 
\left[
\begin{matrix}
 2&  3&  5&  0&  0&  0&  0&  0&  0\\
  7& 11& 13& 17& 19& 23&  0&  0&  0\\
  0&  0&  0& 29& 31& 37& 41& 43& 47
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$
and
$$
b^T = 
\left[
\begin{matrix}
650&  1020&  1220&  8142&  8778& 10506&  9348&  9804& 10716
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$
Then
$$
Q = 
\left[
\begin{matrix}
-0.32444284 & -0.03206836 &  0.02368851\\
-0.48666426 & -0.06260965 &  0.04624899\\
-0.81110711 &  0.05039313 & -0.0372248 \\
0.         & -0.49324188 & -0.01760663\\
0.         & -0.55127033 & -0.00108367\\
0.         & -0.66732725 &  0.00562028\\
0.         & 0.         & -0.5400102 \\
0.         & 0.         & -0.56635216\\
0.         & 0.         & -0.61903608
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$
$$
R = 
\left[
\begin{matrix}
 -6.164414  & -18.16879917&   0.        \\
  0.        & -34.46584885& -56.08450291\\
  0.        &   0.        & -75.92449232
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$
so that, and here lies the problem
$$
Q^T b = \left[
\begin{matrix}
-1696.83606503 & -15889.19305961 & -17310.78424806
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$
How am I to partition this vector into $d_1$ and $d_2$? What are the sizes of the subvectors?
